# How to show a message on window close button in wpf?

Tags: .net, wpf

I want to show a message when user click on close button that ARE YOU WANT TO CLOSE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if you are using vb or c# but on Vb you just need to go on your application.xaml.vb window using this code:

```
Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
msgBox("Closing")
End Sub
```

and then every time you press the close button it will show a messagebox.

Comment: There are no finalize() in C#

Comment: Overridding the `Finalize()` method to show a message box is not what you should be doing. `Finalize()` is reserved for cleaning up resources when the object is being collected by the GC... not showing closing messages. If you're going to do an override, at least override the `OnClosing()` method.

Answer (score 5):

Just add a handler to the `Closing` event and show a message box with your message.  Cancel the event depending on which option the user chooses.

In C#:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Closing += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(MainWindow_Closing);
    }

    void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("ARE YOU WANT TO CLOSE?", "CLOSING", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

subscribe the window closing event and put your messagebox into it.

with e.Cancel=true you can cancel the window-close-action.